# How to reference a Cell in a =IMPORTHTML string?

Tags: google-sheets

Basicaily i just want to be able to modify the URL in an =IMPORTHTML string.

for example.

If I have

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/PG/key-statistics?p=PG","table", 1)
```

but I want to have the URL change the PG to a value in a cell.

I tired

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/"B1"/key-statistics?p="B1"","table", 1)
```

and

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/&B1&/key-statistics?p=&B1&","table", 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To concatenate values in a string you can use either the `&` operator or the `=CONCATENATE()` function.

In your case I think you can opt for the `&` operator like this:

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/" & B1 & "/key-statistics?p=" & B1,"table", 1)
```

### Reference:

[CONCATENATE()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094123?hl=en)

Comment: This worked great.. But since then I have encountered another issue.I can't seem to find a table ID  (the 1) at the end of the string.

in this URL you can find a TABLE named "Valuation Measures" I can't seem to get this data to come it. I got all the other data in not problem.

https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/2618.TW/key-statistics?p=2618.TW

Comment: If this solves the issue please accept the answer so that can be helpful for other users. The index identifies which table will be returned from the function. I don't know which table index is the one you want. You should try with a different index.